# iterate inside my .html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Good Morning,

i am developing an application on rails and i want to show a map with locatión of some cities that i alredy have.

I try writing:

```
<%=var="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&" %>
<%= @itinerary_city_visits.each do |city_visit| %>
<%= var = "#{var}&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C#{city_visit.longitude},#{city_visit.latitude}" %>
<% end %>
<%= var = "#{var}&sensor=false" %>
<%= image_tag var %>
```

but the application prints several times the url but don't show the map. I don't know what to do ... I appreciate your collaboration

*edit

I am trying to show only one map with all the cities.

Comment: What kinds of api or gems are you using?

Comment: no gem, url given by developers.google.com